# MySQL temporary variable in table name

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a series of tables with the same prefix, and I need to select data from the latest version --whose postfix with the highest numeric number. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT
    @latest_version_number :=
    MAX(
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table_name,'_',-1) AS UNSIGNED)
    )
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE lower(table_name) like '{table_prefix}%';

SELECT
    *
FROM CONCAT('`{table_prefix}', CAST(@latest_version_number AS CHAR), '`')
```

It behaved like what I expected when ran as 2 separate queries in the console. But I got "syntax error" trying to run it as a single query. What's the cleanest way to refactor this into a single query? Thanks

Comment: Well... those are two queries. You need to run them separately. If you want to perform a single call, you should create a stored procedure that can include many queries.

Comment: I know... I'm asking specifically on how to refactor into one query. Maybe using CTE's or something similar.

Comment: Since you are assembling the name of the table at runtime, from the result of the previous query you need to use Dynamic SQL. You have two options: 1) Perform two separate calls from your app, since you need to assemble the second query at runtime, or 2) Create a stored procedure that assembles the second query in the server and requires a single call from the app.

Comment: Fix your database model!  Having the same entities spread across multiple tables is just an unnecessary complication in a data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I'm aware that you can use a variable in a table name in MySQL is using the prepare + execute statements.

Here is an example I found online that gives you exact instructions.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/set-user-defined-variable-with-table-name-in-mysql-prepare-statement

Comment: This rather ignores the elephant in the room